# Is there a relation between packing number and disagreement coefficient in the active learning setting?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning, packing, sample-complexity

This is a question for active learning experts: Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the input space equipped with a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hypothesis class, $h \in \mathcal{H}$ our target model such that $\mathcal{D}$ is realizable by h, and let $M$ be the packing number of $\mathcal{H}$ with the classic semi-metric distance (probability of error); so that $\mathcal{F} \triangleq \{h_1, \dots, h_M\}$ is tha packing set of $\mathcal{H}$.

The disagreement coefficient over $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as: $\theta_h(\epsilon_0) \triangleq \sup_{\epsilon > \epsilon_0} \frac{\mathbb{P}[DIS(\mathcal{B}(h, \epsilon))]}{\epsilon}$.

I'm currently working on the lower bounds and wondering if any work found this link between the packing number and the disagreement coefficient. If no work exists that measures lower bounds in terms of the disagreement coefficient, that means the disagreement coefficient is not the right information complexity to characterize the hypothesis space for tight bounds.